# Is there a theorem that states "whatever can be done with trust can be done without"?

Tags: trust

I remember hearing something like this when I first learned the protocols that removed the need of a trusted third party, but I can't find this theorem or "law" anywhere. Any pointers?

Comment: I first learned about such protocols in a book called "Applied Cryptography." Although it's a 72 cubic inch book, it never explicitly says that.

Comment: You don't need a trusted third party if you don't need a trusted second one. Or if you're willing to travel all over the continent checking IDs and personally collecting public keys for the sites you visit.  (But wait...where do IDs come from?  D'oh!)